# HttpURLConnection returning 400 status on post call without payload

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, bufferedreader, spring-jdbc, dataoutputstream

Actually there are two POST URLs. First POST url is login as follows and even it contains body as json as follows.

```
String loginUrl = "http://00.00.00.00:0000/url/vs1/login";
json = `{"email": "qqqq@mail.com", "password": "/JGgdwd6vhsvJJFGDF7ttd="}`
```

Second POST url without payload as follows.

```
String SiteLoginUrl = "http://00.00.00.00:0000/url/vs1/site/1/login";
```

So first, above first url need to login then only i can login to second url.
Hence first URL is logging in successfully but after getting response i need to login for second URL which doesn't consists of payload or json. So after calling second URL with **POST** is returning **400 error**. For second URL i have written code below.

```
// java HttpURLConnection for POST without json or payload data     
        String SiteLoginUrl = "http://00.00.00.00:0000/url/vs1/site/1/login";
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(SiteLoginUrl).openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true); 
        conn.setUseCaches(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ContentType","application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        wr.writeBytes(obj.toString()); //String Empty Object
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();         
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
```

In POSTMAN i checked it is working fine (returning successful login response) with text `{}`(String Empty Object) payload.

Comment: You say the second request is without payload but you're sending the string representation of a JSONObject which is more than nothing.

Comment: Also. HTTP is stateless. Is the first response containing some cookies? If yes, you have to set them as request header in the second request.